# daterangepicker apply buttom not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, daterangepicker

I am using daterangepicker please check my code here **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chinmay235/5ef2rqmq/1/)**

I have set default date

```
"endDate": "08/03/2015",
"endDate": "08/03/2015",
```

And I have set an `alert()` for checking my code is working or not.

```
alert("New date range selected: '" + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "' to '" + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "'");
```

When I am clicking on `book_date` textbox range calendar is appearing.
If i am changeing any date and clicking apply button its working fine. My `alert()` box is showing perfect. But when i click apply button without change any date. That time `alert()` box is not showing.

Also `book_date` is getting default date after clicking textbox and click anywhere in the page. So i don't want to put any default date without cilcking particular date. textbox should be blank while clicking ouside of calendar.

My Edited Code:

```
$('#book_date').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    alert("New date range selected: '" + picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "' to '" + picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "'");
});
```

My textbox Calendar getting default value if i am not select any and clicking outside anywhere of the page.

Answer (score 8):

The callback function only executes when a **new** date is selected. As a possible work-around you could use the `apply.daterangepicker` event, which is triggered when the apply button is clicked:

```js
$('#book_date').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  var startDate = picker.startDate;
  var endDate = picker.endDate;
  alert("New date range selected: '" + startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "' to '" + endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "'");
});
```

See an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5ef2rqmq/2/).

**Extended answer**

There is no in-built way to prevent the dates being set when you click off the date picker, so you could try this:

Customise the `hide` function so the dates are cleared whenever the date picker is closed:

```
$('#book_date').on('hide.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
    $('#book_date').val('');
});
```

Update the `apply` function to populate the dates field accordingly. So the dates are only set when the apply button is clicked:

```
$('#book_date').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
    var startDate = picker.startDate;
    var endDate = picker.endDate;  
    //MM/DD/YYYY format
    $('#book_date').val(startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
});
```

Updated demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5ef2rqmq/6/).

Comment: you have done 1  but My main solution not solved yet. Can you please say me If I click textbox without clicking any  calendar date then i will click outside any where the page the textbox should be blank. But now is taking default date.

Comment: Totally textbox value getting null. `Apply` button also not working

Comment: What you have changed here. Still here getting null value in my book_date id but your demo coking working fine.

Comment: I have added a hide function and updated the apply function, as described in my answer.

Comment: Yes i have also added that. But in my code this is not working.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle and replicate the problem?

Comment: Is it possible to have an `simple get ajax` method immediately after `on apply` ?

Answer (score 3):

When we click apply button then callback function executes but there is condition. If the date range is changed then callback function will execute otherwise it will not execute.
If you want to execute it every time when you click apply button regard less of date range changed or not then do following steps.

1. Open daterangepicker.js
2. Find hide function in DateRangePicker.prototype
3. Comment out the following condition which compares the new selected date range and old selected date range

   ```
   hide: function (e) {
   this.container.hide();
   //Below is the condition that checks for date range changes
   //if (!this.startDate.isSame(this.oldStartDate) || !this.endDate.isSame(this.oldEndDate))
       this.notify();

   this.oldStartDate = this.startDate.clone();
   this.oldEndDate = this.endDate.clone();

   $(document).off('mousedown', this.hide);
   this.element.trigger('hidden', { picker: this });
   ```

   },

or also comment this.notify() in hide function and place it in clickApply: function

```
    clickApply: function (e) {
        this.updateInputText();
        this.hide();
        this.notify();
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function () {
           
            $('#start_date_id').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
                var startDate = picker.startDate;
                var endDate = picker.endDate;
                alert("New date range selected: '" + startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "' to '" + endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "'");
            });

        });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="start_date_id" name="daterange"  />

<script>
$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left'
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I had to put the `on('apply.daterangepicker', ...)` on a timeout (`setTimeout(..., 1000)`) for my apply button to work in certain situations. I could not figure out why.